# Magento - customer_save_after always fired twice

Tags: php, events, magento, observer-pattern

I am using the `customer_save_after` event in magento, and all is working fine apart from 1 annoying thing - it is always fired twice.

There are no other modules rewriting this and I can find no other reason for this happening.  When I look through all of the events getting fired at this time and this event is definately getting fired twice.

Anyone explain this?

I am writing a web service that hooks into this and its turning out to be quite inefficient to duplicate things.

Answer (score 23):

I've noticed this double-save behaviour too.  The way to prevent issue with your observer is to set a flag in the request that can be checked e.g.

```
    if(Mage::registry('customer_save_observer_executed')){
        return $this; //this method has already been executed once in this request (see comment below)
    }

    ...execute arbitrary code here....

    /* Customer Addresses seem to call the before_save event twice, 
    * so we need to set a variable so we only process it once, otherwise we get duplicates
    */
    Mage::register('customer_save_observer_executed',true);
```

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this as well and did a stack trace in the observer for each method, and can tell you at least ONE reason why it fires twice (there may be others):

When a new user creates an account, createPostAction() runs when the form is submitted. This action does a `save()` on the customer.

THEN, after the customer has been created, setCustomerAsLoggedIn() is called by createPostAction(). This in turn calls setCustomer(), which has this little bit of code:

```
 if ((!$customer->isConfirmationRequired()) && $customer->getConfirmation()) {
    $customer->setConfirmation(null)->save(); // here is the second save
    $customer->setIsJustConfirmed(true);
 }
```

Those are the two save()s which dispatch the save event. I only know this for sure for account creation in Magento 1.5. I doubt if it gets fired twice when creating users in the Admin area, or when a user edit's their information... but I don't know for sure.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detective work, this should be marked as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with Jonathans solution, 'customer_save_observer_executed' stays in the session, so event will not be fired again in the browser session. So it's generally a bad idea, because it will not allow to register two or more customers in a row(actually, it will, but events will not be fired)

I suggest the following solution:

```
public function customerRegister(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{       
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();          
    if (!$customer->getId())
        return $this;                

    if(Mage::registry('customer_save_observer_executed_'.$customer->getId()))
        return $this;  

    //your code goes here

    Mage::register('customer_save_observer_executed_'.$customer->getId(),true); 
}
```

Comment: Actually, customer_register_success event is much more better for observing customer registration.

Comment: Yes, however, customer_register_success doesn't fire when the user saves on the account dashboard.

Comment: @VladislavMosalsky registry entries only exists for that request, they do *not* stay in the session (ref http://alanstorm.com/magento_registry_singleton_tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

I used a static var:

```
private static $_handleCustomerFirstSearchCounter = 1;

public function Savest($observer) {
    if (self::$_handleCustomerFirstSearchCounter > 1) {
        return $this;
    }

    $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $model = Mage::getModel('customerst/customerst')
        ->setQueryText(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('q'))
        ->setCustomerId($customerData->getId())
        ->setCustomerName($customerData->getName())
        ->save();

    self::$_handleCustomerFirstSearchCounter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between these 2 events is one of them can't get customer info, while the other can. So the solution is

```
    public function email_CustomerRegister(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $customer_email                 = $customer->getEmail();


        if(empty($customer_email)){
            return;
        }

        // do something
    }
```