# Magento Customer Save Events

Tags: php, magento, events

I'm working on an existing magento page. A logged in user can change his profile informamation (firstname, lastname, email, etc.) and they can change their billing and shipping addresses.

What I need to do is send notification emails whenever a customer changes their basic information or one of their addresses. I created an observer for two events:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <customer_save_after>
            <observers>
                <ext_customer_save_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>ext/observer</class>
                    <method>customerSaveAfter</method>
                </ext_customer_save_after>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_after>
        <customer_address_save_after>
            <observers>
                <ext_customer_save_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>ext/observer</class>
                    <method>customerAddressSaveAfter</method>
                </ext_customer_save_after>
            </observers>
        </customer_address_save_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

And in customerSaveAfter I send an email and in customerAddressSaveAfter I check if the current ID is the same as the defaultbillingaddress or the defaultshipping address and send the notification accordingly. This is working fine, until the user checks the "Set as Default Shipping Address" checkbox. In this case, I suddenly receive 5 emails:

- Billing Address changed
- Shipping Address changed
- Shipping Address changed
- Billing address changed
- customer info changed

So, suddenly the events are fired multiple times and the customer_address_save_after somehow triggers the customer_save_after event. Is there a way to prevent this or to check which event triggered another event or something like this? Or are there other ways to handle this problem?

I'd be really thankful for any hints, thank you very much.

Comment: You are receiving 5 mails, might be because of - customer_save_after event will be triggered everytime whenever customer changed any data (including address, basic profile info etc). And your second customer_address_save_after event specifically triggers on change of address.

Comment: but if the customer edits an address I just get one email. the customer_save_event is only triggered when the checkbox is checked

Comment: okay, so may be this is relevant to your problem and can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838346/magento-customer-save-after-always-fired-twice

Comment: Thank you very much. I went for a different approach in the end, but your link still helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't really solve the problem, with mage_registry I alawys got an error so I decided to go for a totally different approach.

In my extension I removed the observers and instead created 2 new Controllers, AccountController and AddressController, to overwrite Magentos Standard Controllers for handling customer and address saving.

In my config.xml I added this:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <my_ext before="Mage_Customer_AccountController">My_Ext</my_ext>
                    <my_ext before="Mage_Customer_AddressController">My_Ext</my_ext>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

And, for example, my AccountController looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Customer').DS."AccountController.php";
class My_Ext_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController{
    public function editPostAction(){
        //I copied the code from the Magento AccountController here and at the proper line I added my own code
    }
}
```

And the same for my AddressController. This worked really nicely.

Thanks for your help, everyone.